# How do I find an intermediate switch's IP address on my LAN?

Tags: networking, switch, ip-address, nmap, scanning

I use a D-Link DGS-1005A (you can see the manual [here](https://gluhcdn.azureedge.net/cswit/productmanuals/dlk0272_0.pdf)) switch that sits between my main router provided by the ISP and my machine and I am trying to find its IP Address so that I can play with the device's settings.

The problem is that I can't seem to find the device's IP when I scan the network using nmap on my Linux machine. More specifically, I've tried the following command: `sudo nmap -sn <my-machine's-ip-address` but none of those IP addresses seem to be the switch's address.

So to summarise, my main goal is to find the settings page of the switch and to do that I've tried scanning the network but none of the devices' addresses seem to be the switch's address. (I assume none of the addresses are the switch's address because when I plug every address on a URL field and navigate to it using my browser, none seem to navigate to the settings page of the device)

Comment: Please specify which exact model of switch it is. D-Link makes a whole selection and the answer depends on the exact model. You can EDIT your question to add that information.

Comment: We need the exact model of the switch. Some switches are unmanaged and have no settings page.

Comment: Sorry for that. I've updated the question.

Comment: It's not a managed switch. Therefore it has no IP address of its own. See for contrast - https://support.dlink.com/resource/PRODUCTS/DGS-1100-SERIES/DGS-1100-05_05PD_08_08P_REVB_MANUAL_v2.21_WW_EN.pdf which *are* managed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switches are "layer 2" devices that forward link-layer frames (not IP packets), so they don't *need* to have an IP address to do their job, and they might actually **not have one** – and even if they do have one, it might not always be in your configured subnet.

In particular, "Unmanaged" switches don't have any configuration to offer (in other words, no remote management, hence 'unmanaged'), and don't speak IP at all<sup>1</sup> – so no IP address.

As noted in comments, your "DGS-1005A 5-Port Gigabit Unmanaged Desktop Switch" is an unmanaged switch, meaning it doesn't have an IP address, and there is nothing that you could configure in it. It's a completely fixed-function device.

(Typically unmanaged switches won't even have a *MAC* address, either, as they don't need one in order to just forward data; they're essentially invisible to hosts. And nearly all protocols that a switch might participate in by itself are features of a "managed" switch.)

---

Only "managed" switches will usually have an IP address, but it *might* be configured statically (not DHCP) and that static address might belong to a completely different IP subnet than yours, so your PC wouldn't actually know where to access it (it'd try to use the gateway, instead of looking for a local host via ARP).

To access a known address you'd usually need to change the computer's IP address to something within the same subnet. For example, if the sticker on the bottom says "Default address: 192.168.0.1" but your router uses 192.168.1.x, you have to ignore the router and configure the PC as (e.g.) 192.168.0.7 instead – *or* configure the router to handle both subnets simultaneously.

To *discover* unknown addresses that might be in other subnets you'd probably need a scanning tool that specifically uses ARP (e.g. `arp-scan`), and in some cases even Wireshark to watch for ARP queries that the switch itself might make.

Finally, if the switch is (or was) managed by another network administrator, its "management" IP address might have been configured only for a specific port, or a specific VLAN tag. To find such an address without factory-resetting the whole thing, in the worst case you'd need to repeat the scan across all 4094 possible VLAN IDs. (Then realize that you don't know the password, and factory-reset it anyway.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Except for a certain brand that has an "Unmanaged Pro" line, which contrary to its name *does* support remote management over IP (although offers very little)... I've also seen old ZyXEL switches run a proprietary link-layer protocol that works without IP.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

Your switch is an UNMANAGED switch.

There is nothing that you can configure and (obviously) it doesn't have any configuration interface which would need an IP-address.